# Preserve the order of keys when using Reflect.fields() in haxe?

Tags: json, haxe, jsonparser

I'm using `Reflect.fields()` to get items in my Json parsed as an object.

```
var test = haxe.Json.parse('{
    "a": [
        "value"
    ],
    "b": [
        "value"
    ],
    "c": [
        "value"
    ],
    "d": [
        "value"
    ]
}');

Sys.println(Reflect.fields(test));
```

However the above prints out: `[d,c,a,b]`. Is there a way to preserve the order in which the keys are defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do this with the standard library - the order of JSON keys in an object is not defined.

If you write your own json parser (probably best as a SAX parser), you can keep track of the order of the keys from the input yourself.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Chii's answer, you don't *have to* write your own JSON parser - you can take the [standard library parser](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/tree/development/std/haxe/format) and add the needed logic to it - e.g. I had it store the key order in a separate object field before.